# mix-blend-mode: hue not working in safari - How can i solve this?

Tags: html, css, safari

I am trying to use the `mix-blend-mode: hue` in safari on macOS, but i doesn't work. Why? My code looks like this:

```css
.hue-demo {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600639853470-112d492226da?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=933&q=80');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.hue-demo::before {
  content: '';
  mix-blend-mode: hue;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #23a6d5 38%, #FFEB3B 69%);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom; 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="hue-demo" />
```

How can i solve this? I have now problems in chrome and firefox

Note: This Demo works in Safari inside the stackoverflow page. I don't know why this works, instead of my web project

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Now i am using `background-blend-mode: hue` like this:

```css
.hue-demo {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #23a6d5 38%, #FFEB3B 69%), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600639853470-112d492226da?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=933&q=80');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: hue;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hue-demo" />
```